# Should an SQLiteOpenHelper (Android) be used in a service or an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, sqliteopenhelper

I searched, but couldn't find any **concrete** answer to this question; so here goes.

I know that I shouldn't access the database from the UI thread. Also, the AsyncTask isn't good for longer time tasks(memory leaks etc.). So I'm guessing I should make use of a service.

Should I open the SqliteOpenHelper as a service in a new Thread? Do you have any example code of how to do this?

Is the SQLiteOpenHelper automatically run in another thread by Android? I didn't find any example code online that didn't run the SQLiteOpenHelper on the UI thread. Why is this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the SQLiteOpenHelper automatically run in another thread by Android?

In Java, objects are not run on threads. Methods are called on threads.

I am not aware of any `SQLiteOpenHelper` method that automatically uses its own thread — thread management is the responsibility of the objects that call methods on the `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

> I didn't find any example code online that didn't run the SQLiteOpenHelper on the UI thread

In Java, objects are not run on threads. Methods are called on threads.

[Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsROWID) that calls methods like `getReadableDatabase()` on a `SQLiteOpenHelper` from a background thread. [Here is another such sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/FTS). [Here is yet another sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EmPubLite-AndroidStudio/T14-Database/EmPubLite). The first two use `AsyncTask`; the latter one uses a regular `Thread` with an event bus.

> Should I open the SqliteOpenHelper as a service in a new Thread?

A `SQLiteOpenHelper` cannot *be* a `Service`, as Java does not support multiple inheritance, and both `SQLiteOpenHelper` and `Service` are concrete classes.

You are certainly welcome to use an instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper` from inside a `Service`, if you wish.

> Also, the AsyncTask isn't good for longer time tasks(memory leaks etc.).

Proper use of an `AsyncTask` will not trigger a memory leak (e.g., manage it by a retained fragment). The decision of whether to use an `AsyncTask` versus something else (e.g., an ordinary thread, `IntentService`) is more based on how long the work will take and what the risks are of your process being terminated before that work completes.